# scaffolding withFormat views is not working

Tags: grails, csv, scaffolding

I would like to use withFormat within my scaffolding controller and added a scaffolding view  'list.csv.gsp'. But without generating my list.csv.gsp view, grails doesn't use the scaffolding list.csv.gsp view.

After generating de list.csv.gsp view it works fine. But I won't create all these views, because they are all the same.

My scaffolding controller list action ends with the code below:

```
  withFormat {
        html {
            [${propertyName}List: ${propertyName}List, ${propertyName}Total: ${propertyName}List.getTotalCount(), params: cleanParams(params)]
        }
        csv {
            response.setContentType('text/csv')
            response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename=\${message(code: '${domainClass.propertyName}.label')}.csv")
            [${propertyName}List: ${propertyName}List]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you still have a problem with this but the grails docs for with format have this quote:

> Grails ignores the HTTP Accept header unless you add a grails.mime.use.accept.header = true setting to your Config.groovy file. In other words, withFormat() will be completely unaffected by the Accept header without that setting.

See [withFormat](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html) in the grails docs.

Answer (score 0):

On your view you might need to write it generic and put in a common directory and refer your controller template to use it. Maybe make it as a _template and render it.
hope this helps.